# Unable to write on a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm facing an issue while trying to set a value in a specific cell. I have specified in other cells also and they are showing fine. but only one cell making me frustrating, my goal is to copy a template sheet to a temporary sheet then writing on it and then export it to a pdf. after exporting it all fields are showing correctly but one field is not writing as per the need. What else i can do?

Here is the link of my template sheet, please check 2nd sheet. [Template](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OZYXB5BM5od-5a-V6d6MirV_m7rP22C5MgDbhjhoeHw/edit?usp=sharing)
Here is the output link. % of Ownership of owner 2 is not writing. [Pdf Template](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fLF2Yob0YSloeHy17CmVWoWaJ7mNrGd8/view?usp=sharing)

```
function onSubmit(){
  var newSheet;
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1OZYXB5BM5od-5a-V6d6MirV_m7rP22C5MgDbhjhoeHw');
  newSheet = file.makeCopy();
  newSheet.setName('Temp');

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.open(newSheet);
  var sheets = s.getSheets();
  var sheet1 = sheets[1];
      let ownership = '30%';
    setCell('J28:L28',ownership,sheet1);//Only this specific Cell not writing.
 }
function setCell(range,info,sheet1){
  var cell = sheet1.getRange(range);
  var value = '';
  value = cell.getValue()+' '+info;
  cell.setValue('');
  cell.setValue(value);
}
```

Comment: The `onSubmit` function declaration has an error (the parenthesis after the function name are missing).

Comment: Please add some sample data and and corresponding expected result.

Comment: Your current example is not reproducible.  getData() is undefined.  ownerShip is undefined and setCell seems odd since the range that you dealing with is actually three cells.  So I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I updated the code, you can see now and the cell I have is merged with 3 cells.

Comment: `% of Ownership of owner 2 is not writing` if that is in merged cell `J28:L28`, I cannot reproduce this. `30%` is showing up on that cell after running `onSubmit`.

Answer (score 0):

A merged range only has a value in its top-left corner cell. Use `Spreadsheet.getRange(string)`, `Range.getDisplayValue()` and a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), like this:

```js
function onSubmit() {
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById('1OZYXB5BM5od-5a-V6d6MirV_m7rP22C5MgDbhjhoeHw');
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.open(file.makeCopy().setName('Temp'));
  const cell = ss.getRange('Template!J28');
  const oldValue = cell.getDisplayValue();
  const valueToAppend = '30%';
  cell.setValue(`${oldValue} ${valueToAppend}`);
}
```

Comment: `function setCell(range,info,sheet1){
  var cell = sheet1.getRange(range);
  var value = ' '+info;
  let oldValue = cell.getDisplayValue();
  console.log(\`${oldValue} ${value}\`);
  cell.setValue((\`${oldValue} ${value}\`));
}` changed the setCell function to this and it's still working for all the fields and not for the specific "% ownership Owner 2" field. I'm confused why it's not writing to that J28 cell. as the technique is same for all.

Comment: I'm even getting proper value on console. but not on the pdf document.

Comment: Have you tested the function I gave you? When you do, are there any errors in the console? Does the value in cell J28 get updated? Check `=len(J28)`.